# Is there a way to discourage a tomato plant from growing too tall?

Tags: vegetables, tomatoes

I have a tomato plant that is now 6ish feet tall and still seems to be growing up and up. Is there a way to discourage this upward growth and keep it to a height that I won't need a ladder to harvest?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless perhaps it's a specialist variety then if it's 6ft then it has already put out more than four trusses - I presume. So you should have already pinched out the top to retard upward growth and force the plant to focus its energies on its fruit.

I work on the 4 trusses principle. However I didn't try to answer [this question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1111/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-trusses-for-a-tomato-plant) because I hoped for a more expert gardener than me to chip in and confirm it.

Answer (score 6):

Simply [pinch out (prune)](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/331/51) the growing tips. This will also help the plant put more energy into ripening fruit.